Filtering list on current month birthdays
I'm trying to achieve a Birthday calendar where only this month's birthdays are shown.
I've seen countless of topics about this or similar questions, but I cannot replicate any of the code because I get errors all the time.
I have two columns: Name and Birthday



Name
Birthday




Caitlin
21-3-2024


Jack
22-4-2024


Hank
23-5-2024



How can I make sure that only rows with xx-currentmonth-xxxx are shown?

You can create two calculated columns to get the start date and end date of the month of the date column. Then check if the start date of the month of the date value is less than or equal to the current date [Today] and end date of the month of the date column is greater than or equal to the current date [Today]. If yes, it is in the current month.
Create two calculated columns named "Start of Month" and "End of Month". Return as the Date and Time data type.
"Start of Month" =DATE(YEAR([date]), MONTH([date]), 1)

"End of Month" =DATE(YEAR([date]), MONTH([date])+1,1)-1

Create/modify a view and add filter as follow: enter image description here


If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

How's going today? Do you have further concerns regarding this issue? Please feel free to talk with us if you have other questions. If the above info is helpful to this question, you can click "Accept Answer". Have a nice day!
